# How can I create an acceptable private key file for WinSCP assembly to authenticate with?

Tags: c#, private-key, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to use the WinSCP assembly to upload to our FTP server. We have a common private key stored in our DB that we retrieve and use for authentication (this is currently working for our Java upload usith `JSch`). However WinSCP needs a file path name.

I'm trying to write our private key to a file for WinSCP to take for authentication but I'm getting the following error:

> "C:\[..path..].\key.txt (not a recognised key file format)"

**Upload Code:**

```
String host = token.hostName;
String user = token.userID;
String sshKey = token.sshKey;

//write key to temp file
String keyFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@".\key.txt";
FileStream temp = new FileStream(keyFile, FileMode.Create);
temp.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sshKey), 0 , 0);
temp.Close();

try {
    // Setup session options
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = host,
        UserName = user,
        SshPrivateKeyPath = keyFile,
        GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true
    };

    using (Session session = new Session()) {
        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
        session.DisableVersionCheck = true;

        // Upload files
        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

        TransferOperationResult transferResult;
        transferResult = session.PutFiles(@resultsFolder+"*", depthDir, false, transferOptions);

        // Throw on any error
        transferResult.Check();

        // Print results
        foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers) {
            Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
        }
    }               
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
} finally {
    // delete file with key
    File.Delete(keyFile);
}
```

Comment: Can I assume that you want to read the content of the file?

Comment: What format has your `key.txt`? Show us.

Comment: `key.txt` is just a long string of characters (a private key)

Comment: Show us how you use the key file in JSch.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but your winscp code works. I just needed to convert my private key to PuTTY standard. To do that just convert your key by using

winscp.exe /keygen oldformat.key /output=newformat.key

You can use PuTTY but I found winscp much simpler as you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am assuming correctly you will need to adjust your code from this

```
String keyFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@".\key.txt";
```

to this

```
var keyFilePath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory} \\key.txt";
var keyText = File.ReadAllText(keyFilePath);
```

I have split it across two variables here so that you have a clear understanding, but you can do it all in the one line.

Comment: I don't think your change accomplishes anything besides requiring a new version of C# -- you've removed an extraneous `.` (which might be harmless if `BaseDirectory` ended with a slash) and inserted an extraneous space (which is not harmless).